# Access var - scope issue

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a javascript object which is structured like the following:

```
var object = {
    item1: {
        name: 'item1',
        details: {
            name: 'detail1',
            warn_lvl: 1 
        }, 
        check: function(res) {
            console.log('Warn lvl of item1 = '+//access var?)
        }
    }
}
```

In my `console.log()` from my `check()` function, I would like to print the `warn_lvl` of item1, but I can't figure out how to access it.

I tried several things with `this`, but nothing which work.

What is the proper way to access this var?

**Edit**

To be more precise (sorry, my mistake), I call the check function from another Javascript file, like this (only relevant parts):

```
var fetchMetrics = function (config, metrics) {
        Object.keys(metrics).forEach(function(section) {
            var metric = metrics[section];
            doRequests(metric, section);
};

var doRequests = function(metric, section) {

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: metric.url,
        data: metric.params,
        var result;

        if (!query_result.length) {
            result = state_retriever.RESULT_UNKNOWN
        } else {
            result = metric.check(query_result);
        }   
};
```

Comment: "I tried several things with this" — Such as? Questions asking for debugging help need a [mcve].

Comment: How does your code snippet at the end match up with your original one? If `metric` corresponds to `object.item1` (as it would seem to, give that that's where `check` is), xale94's `this.details.warn_lvl` would work the way you're calling it above (`metric.check(query_result)`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I use each objects defined in my `object` var to do some actions. The `check()` function is called after I received a result from the Ajax call. So `this` is not applicable (as I understand).

Answer (score 2):

**If** you're calling `check` via `object.item1.check("res arg here")`, then you can use `this.details.warn_lvl`:

```js
var object = {
  item1: {
    name: 'item1',
    details: {
      name: 'detail1',
      warn_lvl: 1
    },
    check: function(res) {
      console.log('Warn lvl of item1 = ' + this.details.warn_lvl)
    }
  }
};
object.item1.check();
```

**But** you've said you're calling `check` a different way. You can reliably access it via `object.item1.details.warn_lvl` regardless of how you call `check`:

```js
var object = {
  item1: {
    name: 'item1',
    details: {
      name: 'detail1',
      warn_lvl: 1
    },
    check: function(res) {
      console.log('Warn lvl of item1 = ' + object.item1.details.warn_lvl);
    }
  }
};
var c = object.item1.check;
c();
```

Comment: @TJCrowder, I'm just curious, why you delete your answer? I mean it was correct. An alternate could have been `this..`

Comment: I do not call it this way. The deleted answer fro @T.J Crowder did the trick. `object.item1.details.warn_lvl`

Comment: @Rajesh: Because it was wrong, and there was a correct answer posted by the time I realized it.

Comment: @Mornor: Oh, wow, okay; would you add how you're calling it to the question?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Respect.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Done.

Comment: xale94 - I think the reason this answer got an initial downvote was that it was a code dump answer. Code dumps are not usually *useful* answers. Always be sure to say *what* you changed, and *why*, and flag up your assumptions (such as how the function is called).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for the explanation.